# MIPS effective address

Tags: assembly, mips

```
    .data
space:  .asciiz "\n"
mgs:    .asciiz "Lines by Z\n\n"
mgs2:   .asciiz "Enter text? "
lines:  .word   0:10
counter:.word   0
inbuf:  .space  32


        .text
main:

    la    $a0, mgs        # display message
    jal    puts
    
doLoop:   
    
    la  $a0, mgs2       # ask for input
    jal puts
    la  $a0, inbuf
    li  $a1, 32            # maximum of length
    jal gets              # call function
    
    lb  $t0, inbuf
    beq $t0, '\n', endDoloop
    jal strdup            # call stdup fucntion
    
    lw    $t0, counter        # counter
    
    sll    $t0, $t0, 2      # * counter 4
    la    $t1, lines          # get the address of array
    add    $t1, $t1, $t0      
    sw    $v0, ($t1)          # store address to the array
     
    lw    $t0, counter        #  counter++
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    sw    $t0, counter
    blt    $t0, 10, doLoop     # if counter < 10, loop the code from doLoop
    
endDoloop:  

    la    $t0, lines        # get address of array
    li    $t1, 0           
    lw    $t2, counter        # max number of lines in array
    la    $a0, space
    jal    puts
    
print:   
 
    lw    $a0, ($t0)          # get line in array
    jal    puts               # print message
    addi    $t0, $t0, 4       # next element
    addi    $t1, $t1, 1       # count++
    blt    $t1, $t2, print    # if t1 < t2, loop to print
    
   jal end


gets:    
                
    li    $v0, 8          # read input
    syscall
    jr    $ra            # return

puts:      
             
    beqz    $a0, end
    li    $v0, 4         # print message
    syscall
    jr    $ra            # return


strlen:    
                
    move    $v0, $a0        # v0: scan each char
    
while:    
    
    lb  $t3, ($v0)        # if char not equal '\0'
    beqz    $t3, endw
    addiu   $v0, $v0, 1        # go to next char
    b   while
    
endw:    

    sub $v0, $v0, $a0            # length
    jr  $ra                 # return


strdup:    
       
    sub   $sp, $sp, 8        #  a stack for return address # allocate space for the address in $sp
    sw    $ra, ($sp)        # store the current address in the stack, later use for return
    sw    $a0, 4($sp)        
    jal   strlen
    addi  $a0, $v0, 1        # malloc
    jal   malloc
    move  $t4, $v0        
    lw    $t5, 4($sp)     
   
do:    

    lb  $t3, ($t5)         # get the char from the original string
    sb  $t3, ($t4)         
    beqz    $t3, endDo2        
    addiu   $t4, $t4, 1        
    addiu   $t5, $t5, 1        
    b    do
    
endDo2:  
 
    lw    $ra, ($sp)        
        addi  $sp, $sp, 8        # refresh the stack
        jr    $ra            # return


malloc: 
                   
    addi    $a0, $a0, 3        # add 3 to the size

    li    $v0, 9
    syscall
    jr    $ra                # return
    
end:

    li    $v0, 10             # end program
    syscall
```

I am kinda confused about the part inside the label of doLoop,  what does the compute effective address mean? and how does the EA affects the array in this project?

basically, I don't get what the instruction of add $t1, $t1, $t0 mean, it is supposed to compute the EA.

Comment: Where in the code / comments is "effective address" mentioned?  Are you asking about the manual array indexing calculation? (Which is necessary because MIPS's only addressing mode is register + constant, although much more efficient would be to just increment a pointer in `$s0` or some other call-preserved register.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing `lines[counter] = strdup(...)`;

To compute the address for array element `counter` in array `lines` we compute:

To start, `counter` is an index:

```
x = counter << 2
```

Now `x` is a byte offset for array of words instead of an index — it has been scaled ×4

Here, `lines` is a byte pointer to a word array:

```
y = lines + x
```

Now `y` is a byte pointer to the `counter` index element of the `lines` array.

This value `y` can be dereferenced using MIPS' one and only addressing mode, which is `displacement(base)`.

Since the displacement in this case offers no value, the additive identity, 0, is used, which is what the `($reg)` form means.  They could have written `0($reg)` instead — these are 100% equivalent, resulting in the same machine code encoding.

We would call this pointer arithmetic for array indexing.  MIPS cannot do array indexing with variable indexes in one instruction, so it uses several instead.  One of them is `add` which sums the pointer with the byte offset to form an element address.

---

NOTE: one of the authors of this code is aware of `addu`, which should always be used in pointer arithmetic instead of `add` (same for `addiu` vs. `addi`) because pointers are unsigned numbers and `add`/`addi` risk trapping on signed integer overflow, which is unwanted here.

Comment: Thank you for explain, and just one more question. Under the label of strdup, why we need  addi $a0, $v0, 1 this instruction? before it call the procedure of malloc?

Comment: Two reasons, first to transfer strlen's result from $v0 to $a0 for parameter passing to malloc, and, second to reserve one additional byte probably to leave room for a null byte string termination character.